# Entity Framework not able to update Tables

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm new to EF, using 6.0 code-first.

```
using (EmpolyeeContext emp = new EmpolyeeContext())
{
    var callrecordSession = new CallRecordingSession();
    string ucid = new Random().Next(0, 5000).ToString();
    callrecordSession.UCID = ucid;
    callrecordSession.InstrumentationTransactionId = new Random().Next(0, 9000).ToString();
    callrecordSession.ClientName = "IVR";
    callrecordSession.ClientRequestObject = "{string.empty}";
    callrecordSession.CallRecordingStatusName = "Started";
    callrecordSession.ModifiedDatetime = DateTime.Now;

    emp.CallRecordingSessions.Add(callrecordSession);

    var itemToEdit = emp.CallRecordingSessions.Where(c => c.UCID == ucid).FirstOrDefault<CallRecordingSession>();

    if (itemToEdit != null)
    {
        itemToEdit.CallRecordingStatusName = "Inprogress";
        itemToEdit.ModifiedDatetime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    emp.SaveChanges();
}
```

What is wrong with this code? I'm always getting `itemtoEdit` as `null`

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework always queries the data source. This is by design. If they queried your local cache instead, You could get an Id that has already been inserted by a different user in the database. Also Entity framework has to merge results from your memory and the database.

```
    var itemToEdit = emp.CallRecordingSessions.Where(c => c.UCID == ucid).FirstOrDefault<CallRecordingSession>();
```

So all you got to do is call the savechanges before you get the data back.

```
emp.CallRecordingSessions.Add(callrecordSession);

emp.SaveChanges();

var itemToEdit = emp.CallRecordingSessions.Where(c => c.UCID == ucid).FirstOrDefault<CallRecordingSession>();

if (itemToEdit != null)
{
    itemToEdit.CallRecordingStatusName = "Inprogress";
    itemToEdit.ModifiedDatetime = DateTime.Now;
}

emp.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: ok thanks, this works. but wonder how this works in UnitOfWork pattern,where my understanding is only one SaveChanges() will be used to sync the changes(I/U/D) to data source.

Comment: Assuming you are using a repository with your UnitOfWork pattern, The add method to the repository will still add the data only to the local instance of DbContext. It will still not commit the data to the database unless UnitOfWork .SaveChanges is called. So if you add to your repository and try to select back the data you should still see the same behavior as above as UnitOfWork is just adding a level of abstraction. In the end UnitOfWork also saves and fetches the data from the DbContext (in this case EmpolyeeContext). Suprising that it should work in UnitOfWork pattern!

Comment: Yes, i use Repository Pattern. my usecase is i have 3 tables for the context with its own repositories.

Comment: Yes, i use Repository Pattern. my use-case is i have 3 tables for the context with its own repositories. with the following sequence

 1. 1st table insert few rows

 2.  some work done 

 3.  Status of the 1st table got updated

 4. some work done

 5. Stauts of the 2st and 3rd table got updated


my understanding all the changes to the repositories. ( I/U/D) that done in the memory version of DBcontext 
the finally during the end of my work. i can call .SaveChanges in the DBContext which will finally updates the Database (all the tables changes in one transaction).

Answer (score 0):

.SaveChanges() did the tricks.